# Able to successfully rewrite URL in .htaccess test site, but same code doesn't work when used in localhost or in live site

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a url like this: http://test.com/RqM548gy

Into something like this: http://test.com/?url=RqM548gy

So far, the following code has worked in the .htaccess testing site (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (\w+).* ?url=$1 [L]
```

But when I try this on localhost or the actual site, I end up getting a server error.

I'd really appreciate any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the error you recieve?

Comment: 500 error - Internal Server Error

Comment: Go to your error logs and see what the actual error is. You can't debug server errors client side.